# Google says my app is connected to my website but I get an error

Tags: google-home

Google says my app is connected to my website but when I go to "Develop/Settings/Display name" I get the following error:

"Could not reserve your pronunciation because: Your Action's display name is, or sounds like, a reserved brand name. If you are affiliated with this brand, please visit the Connected Properties tab to verify your affiliation and claim the reserved brand name."

When I go to the Connected Properties tab it says "Connected."

Can anyone help?

Comment: Based on your comments below, you're developing an Action with "Girl Scouts" in its name, you've connected the brand to girlscouts.org, and its still being rejected?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue.